# Filtar por whereHas no funciona

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo en laravel un modelo llamada cropGathering que tiene una relación hasMany con cropGatheringTransaction. Este ultimo tiene un atributo tons, entonces lo que necesito es traer todas los cropGatherings, donde la suma de las toneladas de sus transacciones de mayor a 0.

En el modelo cropGathering tengo la relación:

```
 public function cropGatheringTransactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CropGatheringTransaction::class);
    }
```

Lo que probé y no tuve éxito fue lo siguiente:

```
  public function all($perPage, $orderBy = 'id', $order = 'desc')
    {
        return CropGathering::whereHas('cropGatheringTransactions', function ($q) {
                $q->groupBy('crop_gathering_transaction.id')
                    ->havingRaw('SUM(crop_gathering_transaction.tons) > 0');
            })
            ->orderBy($orderBy, $order)
            ->paginate($perPage);
    }
```

También probé lo siguiente, definí en el modelo cropGathering un append:

```
protected $appends = ['tons'];
```

donde obtengo la suma de sus transacciones:

```
 public function getTonsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->cropGatheringTransactions()->sum('tons');
    }
```

Y al probar:

```
CropGathering::sum('tons', '>', 0)
```

me dice:

> Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column \"tons\" does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function all($perPage, $orderBy = 'id', $order = 'desc')
{
    $data = CropGathering::whereHas('cropGatheringTransactions', function ($query) {
                $query->select('crop_gathering_transaction.id')
                      ->selectRaw('SUM(crop_gathering_transaction.tons) AS Total')
                      ->groupBy('crop_gathering_transaction.id')
                      ->havingRaw('Total > 0');
            })->orderBy($orderBy, $order)->paginate($perPage);

     return $data;
}
```

> Me parece que la primer consulta que muestras esta mal escrita;

Debería tener:

- Un `select` que tome por lo menos el `id` de la tabla para poder agrupar posteriormente
- Posterior con el uso de `selectRaw` escribimos la función de agregación para sumar la columna **`tons`**
- Una vez hecho eso agrupamos por la columna de `id` así nos aseguramos que los registros que en este valor coincidan se fusionen en un solo renglón
- Usamos `havingRaw` para filtrar por el alias que le dimos a la función de agregación que es Total **(recordar que si el valor a comparar viene de una función de agregación entonces usaremos `HAVING`)**
- Salvo algún otro comentario me parece que en tu consulta no puedes hacer agrupación como lo intentas puesto que no has puesto en el `select` a dicha columna.

Respecto al tema de la paginación, deberías de checar la [doc. oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#basic-usage), puesto que menciona que no funcionan de forma eficiente las operaciones de paginación sobre resultados que requieren de un `groupBy()`